# Transferring a file using FTP

Tags: c#-2.0

First of all this is not a question seeking Programming help. I am doing a project using FTP in that i employed a logic I want peoples to make comment whether the logic is ok or I have to employ a better one. I transfer files using FTP, for ex if the filesize is 10 MB I will split that file into "X" no of files of "y" size depending upon my network speed, after that I send these files one by one and merge it on the client machine.

the network speed in my client side is very low(1kbps) so I want to split files into size of 512 bytes and send it.

Comment: Why would you need to split up the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better not to split the file but use a client and server that both support resuming file transfers.

Comment: hi divo i already developed my process like the one you said,after that i changed my mind and started doing the splitting type.thnx for ur comment